# How to view AWS site without a domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosts

I have a site hosted with AWS, but the domain is not ready yet. I want to work on it and begin testing.

The site runs through a load balancer.

When I go to Load Balancers in EC2 I can see the DNS name. If I type this into my browser I get a warning that it is unsafe, then when I choose to load anyway I get an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I used the "dig A " command in terminal to get the IP address. I added this IP address to my hosts file, and I get the same error when trying to access it like that.

Comment: Well, you should be able to navigate to the site using the public IP of your web-server (if any). As you have load balancer, you can simply put it in the browser and it would work. What's your set up looks like?

Answer (score 1):

> I get a warning that it is unsafe

It is unsafe because default ALB url does not use HTTPS. It only works with HTTP which is marked as unsecure by all major browsers.

To fix that you need to have **your own domain** and setup a valid, pubic SSL certificate using AWS ACM for that domain.